# sed error near unexpected token '(' where ( is part of search string

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I try to search and replace a given string in a Makefile, that is

```
PROCFLAGS="SQLCHECK=SEMANTICS USERID=$(CONNECT)"
```

Where I want to add `CODE=ANSI_C` to the line

```
PROCFLAGS="SQLCHECK=SEMANTICS USERID=$(CONNECT) CODE=ANSI_C"
```

Sed should do this trick very good.. at least that's what I thought but I can't get behind what syntax error I am doing calling sed:

```
sed -i'.bak' s:(CONNECT):(CONNECT) CODE=ANSI_C:g Makefile
```

I have tried to add `-r` or escape the brackets `\( \)` but I always end up with the error:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

I can only think of something I must be doing wrong here as many other replacements really work fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try quoting the bracketed items. Bash is attempting to run (CONNECT) in a sub shell I think

```
sed -i'.bak' "s:(CONNECT):(CONNECT) CODE=ANSI_C:g" Makefile
```

When you put something in brackets, bash will run it as a command in a subshell.

For example, try `(cd /tmp; pwd); pwd`. You will see the subshell print `/tmp`, but then the second `pwd` will tell you the original directory.

Comment: Yeah, bash will do what it can to expand/interpet things before it passes them to the program being run. For example '*' (a glob) will be expanded before being passed to a program, unless it only matches 0 or 1 things, and then it's passed in literally.

Answer (score 3):

Put your sed code inside quotes.

```
sed -i'.bak' 's:(CONNECT):(CONNECT) CODE=ANSI_C:g' Makefile
```